# What does Thunar's "folder permissions inconsistent" warning mean and what does the "Correct" button do?

Tags: permissions, xubuntu, directory, thunar

I recently discovered that Thunar's properties dialog, for some folders, shows the warning "The folder permissions are inconsistent, you may not be able to work with files in this folder.":

[image: Folder Properties dialog]

What does it mean, and what does the button "Correct folder permissions..." actually do?

### Update 1:

I looked at Thunar's [documentation](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/working-with-files-and-folders#properties) but couldn't find anything about this.

### Update 2:

To answer some questions from the comments:

1. This folder is not (in) my home folder, it is on a shared (NFS) network drive.
2. The permissions of the folder are (as seen by `ls -la`): `drwxrwx--x`, the ownership is me and my group `tech`.  This matches the information shown in Thunar's Properties window (as shown above).

Comment: If this is in your home `~` folder there is a good chance that if you maybe ran something with `sudo` while in the folder that permissions or ownership may have changed.  Without seeing what folder you are in or what the permissions are we can only guess.

Comment: Login out back in may already solve the issue.

Comment: @Terrance I added Update 2 to clarify - please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: @vanadium What issue are you referring to?

Comment: Your issue. Does it persist after logging in? After rebooting? Are the folder permissions in the output of `ls -ld <path-to-folder>` consistent with what Thunar shows?

Comment: @vanadium Yes, the permissions shown in Thunar match the ones from `ls -ld`. Rebooting the machine didn't make a difference. Please note that my question is about the meaning of the warning shown in Thunar and what the button does.